# apache _SESSION does not serialize objects

Tags: php, apache, session, serialization

First, sorry if this post is whiny but I've been frustrated all day long trying to build a basic login system. I think I have it working now and hopefully my code below will help someone else, but I still have questions.

I created a custom User class. I made a login script that verifies the password hash. I then store this User object in session. But when I retrieve the User object on the next page, it is not the right class, it is a __PHP_Incomplete_Class which means I can't use any of my custom functions for that Class object.

So, google and SO and everywhere says I must declare the class before I start the session, and that objects get automagically serialized by apache when I store them in _session. But my object only works if I manually serialize and unserialize the User.

for example, this does NOT work:

```
//page1:
require_once('UserClass.php');
session_start();
$User = new User;
$_SESSION[User] = $User;


//page 2:
require_once('UserClass.php');
session_start();
$User = $_SESSION[User];
$User->doSomething();//##ERROR
```

but this method does work:

```
//page 1:
require_once('UserClass.php');
session_start();
$User = new User;
$_SESSION[szUser] = serialize($User);


//page 2:
require_once('UserClass.php');
session_start();
$User = unserialize($_SESSION[szUser]);
$User->doSomething();//winning!
```

I hate that I have to manually serialize my object. I'm sure it will cause problems in the future when I forget to do it. I wish my server would do it for me.

**Is there something wrong with my first method of code? or is my lunarpages server just being stupid? Perhaps there is a setting that must be changed in the config or htaccess. I'm on a shared host so I have very limited ability on changes. Is there a best-practice way to handle this without abandoning my use of _sesssion?** I just read in another SO answer that I could maybe use the Class __sleep() and __wakeup() functions but those don't support some private properties and I'm not sure they would get triggered by my call to _session anyways.

if it helps at all, here are parts from phpinfo() that may be relevant

```
PHP Version 5.5.26

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Thanks in advance for any configuration changes or other advice you may have.

Comment: It should be `$_SESSION['User']` everywhere.

Comment: thank you for taking a look but my lack of quotes is not the problem. The only time I need to quote array keys is when the key is a reserved name. I've tried with and without quotes and even with different key names. I can read the $_SESSION[User] but it is not properly serialized so I lose the custom class definition. I'm hoping there is a config or htaccess solution